# Xamarin.Android Get frame from TextureView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera, textureview

I want to take a frame image from my TextureView (a preview form camera) when pressing a button. How can I do it?
I create an Activity with a TextureView and two buttons, one for start and stop the camera previewing and one for taking a frame from the preview.
This is my Activity:

```
public class PreviewActivity : Activity
{
    bool myPreviewing;
    Camera myCamera;
    TextureView myTextureView;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Preview);

        Button startPreviewButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.startPreview);
        Button saveImageButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.saveImage);
        myTextureView = FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.myTextureView);

        startPreviewButton.Click += delegate {
            try
            {
                if (!myPreviewing)
                {
                    myCamera = Open();
                    myCamera.SetPreviewTexture(myTextureView.SurfaceTexture);
                    myCamera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                    myCamera.StartPreview();
                }
                else
                {
                    myCamera.StopPreview();
                    myCamera.Release();
                }
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                myPreviewing = !myPreviewing;
            }
        };

        saveImageButton.Click += delegate {
            // do something for take frame
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind a little bit of delay, your **saveImageButton** could call [setOneShotPreviewCallback()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Hardware.Camera.SetOneShotPreviewCallback/p/Android.Hardware.Camera+IPreviewCallback/).

Comment: How about one of the `TextureView#GetBitmap()` methods?